# #29 expected expression - C compilation

Tags: c, signal-processing, code-composer

I'm programing on Code Composer Studio a program that generate and show a sinusoid, this program should normally be implemented in a DSP, but since I don't have the DSK I'm just compiling it and trying to show the result in CCS.

I'm having a problem in the line 18 it shows that an expression is expected and I don't know why. I checked all comas and () {} and it seems correct.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const int sine_table[40] = { 0, 5125, 10125, 14876, 19260, 23170, 26509, 29196, 31163, 32364, 32767, 32364, 31163, 29196, 26509, 23170, 19260, 14876, 10125, 5125, 0, -5126, -10126, -14877, -19261, -23171, -26510, -29197, -31164, -32365, -32768, -32365, -31164, -29197, -26510, -23171, -19261, -14877, -10126, -5126 };

int i = 0;
int x1 = 0;
int x2 = 0;

float y = 0;

float sin1(float phase) {
    x1 = (int) phase % 40; if (x1 < 0) x1 += 40; x2 = (x1 + 1) % 40;
    y = (sine_table[x2] - sine_table[x1]) * ((float) ((int) (40 * 0.001 * i * 100) % 4100) / 100 - x1) + sine_table[x1];
    return y;
}

int main(void) {
    double pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        float x = 40 * 0.001 * i;
        float radians = x * 2 * pi / 40;
        printf("%f %f %f\n", x, sin1(x) / 32768, sin(radians));
        i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the complete and exact error message. Which line in your snippets is affected? Is line 18 this `double pi = 3.14159265....;`?

Comment: You should clearly improve formatting of your code. Writing a line like this is a no-go: ` x1 = (int) phase % 40; if (x1 < 0) x1 += 40; x2 = (x1 + 1) % 40;` Don't squeeze multiple statements in a single line, indent logical blocks.

Comment: Can't reproduce the claimed error in MS VC.

Comment: Can't reproduce in CCS using ticlang.

Comment: Aside, MS VC does *warn* about losing significance. You are freely mixing `float` and `double` seemingly at random. Never use `float` unless you have a very good reason why you can't use `double`.

Comment: The message seems to come from the Keil C compiler. I can imagine that `<math.h>`, which should define `M_PI`, has `pi` as a "convencience definition" macro, so that to the compiler line 18 reads `double 3.14 = 3.14;`, but that's just conjecture.

Comment: Also, you have two different `i` variables. I think you probably don't want the redeclaration in the `for` loop. And why `i = i + 1` at the end of that loop, when you have `i++` in the loop statement? (As it stands, the `i` used in the `sin1` function will *always* be zero.)